# Problem on deriving binet formula

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I'm trying to understand binet formula. I got a good explanation [here](http://faculty.mansfield.edu/hiseri/MA1115/1115L30.pdf). Please look at the link. Everything just fine but one thing. It said that $A_n = A_{n-1} + A_{n-2}$, which is fibonacci. But why $A_n = Cx^n$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving

Answer (score 1):

It is a guess. Many two term linear recurrence equations can be written in closed form.

Answer (score 0):

It's recurrence relation. I think [this explanation](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~mlerma/courses/cs310-04w/notes/dm-recurrences.pdf) helps a lot.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Link-only answers are discouraged since the information at the link may not be available in the future. Please summarize the relevant information at the link.